# Long range wireless mouse or other ways to extend?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mouse, bluetooth

We have an office with 5 very expensive computers running heavy graphics.

once in a while we get a customer we want to get in a meeting room and display what is going on at one of those certain pc's, we do that by extending to the meeting room monitor over wifi.

Now the problem is, the mouse cant reach (its like 15m) and bluetooth is 10m.

So I'm trying to figure out a good way to extend the possibility of using a computer 15 meters away from the monitor, witout a wire.
We dont want to put a wire in there.

is there anything I can do? Like a mouse that works over wifi? or very strong signal mouse?
Or a wireless USB extender?.

**I'm not interested in these suggestions**
1: Just get a PC for the meeting room
2: Just extend the USB with a wire.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [USB extension cable](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20extension%20cable) which can be up to 25 m, put a [Bluetooth adapter](https://www.amazon.com/bluetooth-adapter/s?k=bluetooth%20adapter) in it, and string it closer to the meeting room.

Not all mice work with all Bluetooth adapters, so you might need to invest in another mouse, and plug its adapter into the extension cable. For that matter, you could even add a Bluetooth keyboard, if you need to access the PC "remotely".

From the customer's point of view, your mouse would not appear to be tethered.

Answer (score 0):

There is a compromise, you could use [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy). It's a program that let's you use one mouse across multiple devices thought you local network(wifi).

You will still need a second device to make use of this mouse, but it works like going to a second screen that you can locate to the right or left.

I used this back in 2008 to control my MacBook from my gaming rig using one mouse and one keyboard.

Looks like it will do what you want, but again you will need a second device.

PS: There is another option, there are apps for Android and iPhone that lets you control the mouse and keyboard over wifi of one device I think [Remote Mouse](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/remote-mouse/id385894596).

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a more modern Bluetooth v5 receiver/transmitter and mouse.  They have ranges of up to 800 feet.